# Fill in a select list with jQuery [WTForms]

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to create function which will fill in SelectField: EVENT_NAME, but the problem is when I want to send my list to SelectField. Do You know what I'm doing wrong ?

I create function *autocompleteEvent* which ask db and return result as a list.

```
@app.route('/autocompleteEvent',methods=['GET'])
def autocompleteEvent():
    today = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    json_list = []
    name=current_user.USERNAME
    q = USER.query.filter_by(USERNAME=name).first()
    ID_FEDERATION=q.FEDERATION.ID_FEDERATION

    q = EVENTS.query.filter_by(ID_FEDERATION=ID_FEDERATION).all()
    for i in q:
        if i.DATE>=today:
            json_list.append(i.EVENT_NAME)
        else:
            continue
    print(json_list)
    search = request.args.get('term')
    app.logger.debug(search)
    return jsonify(json_list=json_list)
```

As a result I get:

```
{
  "json_list": [
    "UFC 205", 
    "UFC 206"
  ]
}
```

Flask Form:

```
json_lists = []
class FIGHTS(FlaskForm):
    EVENT_NAME = SelectField(u'Choose eventname',id='EVENT_NAME',choices=json_lists[])
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url_for("autocompleteEvent") }}'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('EVENT_NAME').autocomplete({
            $.each(json_list, function(index, value) {
     ('EVENT_NAME').append($('<option>').text(json_list).attr('value', index));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you tell what specific error you're getting? If it's a traceback, paste the whole error message here.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot about that, I don't get any errors, my selectfild is just empty.So i think the problem is somewhere here:           $('EVENT_NAME').autocomplete({
            $.each(json_list, function(index, value) {
     ('EVENT_NAME').append($('<option>').text(json_list).attr('value', index));

Comment: Can you `console.log()` your `json_list` variable? This way we can be sure if the problem is at the server side.

Comment: Could You please tell me where put the console.log() ?  I'm using Chrome 58.0.3029.110 but see anything except my list. I made prtscrn, please check the link below: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AvdPsdAoxFQkg4IMLVtmS4KN2x6AGw

Comment: I think I got it created please check the link: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AvdPsdAoxFQkg4INC9vW5wJFUpxTRA

Comment: `console.log()` should be independent i.e not inside another method. Just place it after `$('EVENT_NAME').autocomplete({`.

Comment: Thank You for help. I put PrtSc here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvdPsdAoxFQkg4ILCwHK4du7uBiq8w

Comment: That's not right.

Replace `console.log()` with `console.log(json_list)` and place it in a separate line before `$('EVENT_NAME').autocomplete({`.

Comment: I hope now is ok :) https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvdPsdAoxFQkg4ILCwHK4du7uBiq8w

Comment: It seems you don't have jQuery included, or maybe you it's being loaded after Bootstrap, hence the error. Try fixing that first.

Comment: I've already took Google's link to hosted libraries, not from bootstrap like earlier and I've only one error:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", which point on "$('EVENT_NAME').autocomplete({" I tried add "#" before the 'EVENT_NAME',but I got the same error. As You see this name should be correct.

Comment: Really, is it to hard ?